# MDX adding two values of a dimension in a new column

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx, olap

I am new to MDX and using the Calculations from OLAP Pivot table Extensions, I want to add two Values of one Dimension into a new field. For Example, I have the 'Net Sales' Dimension with different values such as, Store, Street, Distribution and I want to create a total column only for Street+Store. Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks,
FP

Comment: you want to add street+store ? sample i/p + o/p data would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Store and Street are members of a hierarchy called `Hier`, which is part of dimension `Dim`, then the expression for the sum of Street + Store would be

```
Sum( { [Dim].[Hier].[Street], [Dim].[Hier].[Store] }, [Measures].[Net Sales] )
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
([Dim].[Hier].[Street], [Measures].[Net Sales]) +
([Dim].[Hier].[Store], [Measures].[Net Sales])
```